# Is there a way to get a custom status message from discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I have what I need to create a user's profile card
I would like to know how to get the user's specified message (text) from discord.py.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can get the custom status from a user with discord.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `member.activities` to get the activities and check if any is `CustomActivity`

```py
@bot.command()
async def status(ctx, m: discord.Member):
    acts = m.activities
    act = [i for i in acts if isinstance(i, discord.CustomActivity)]
    if act:
        act = act[0]
    else:
        return await ctx.send("No Custom Activity")
    text = act.name
    if text:
        await ctx.send(f'Custom Status of {m.name}: **{text}**')
    else:
        return await ctx.send("No text in custom status")
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you.
By the way, is there any way to get only the status message?